# Stepping through working and buggy code simultaniously with gdb

Tags: gdb

I have a C code that has a bug and an older version that does not show the bug. Now, I'd like to use two gdb sessions simultaneously, side by side, to step though the codes. I am looking for a way to do that without having to type, say, `n` in each gdb session. In other words I am looking for a method to link the sessions that when I press a gdb command in one it will be propagated to the other. Can that be done?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think such a method exists. In general the differences could be huge and the compiler might have generated wildly different code. You might want to look at something like `git bisect` though or the equivalent for your version control system to help track it down

Comment: @Flexo, thanks for the comment. It does not have to perfect or a general solution.

Comment: did either answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with two panes open in tmux/screen. see this link http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Screen_vs_tmux and the section on synchronize panes. for tmux:

```
ctrl-b :set-window-option synchronize-panes on|off
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do it in single gdb session using [Multiple Inferiors](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Inferiors-and-Programs) (not tested).

First you can create 2 inferiors, one for new buggy version and another for older one. Then you will need to define [Command Hook](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Hooks) for `next` command something like this:

```
define hookpost-next
inferior 2
next
inferior 1
end
```

Comment: fwiw there is a example of doing something similar with python here: https://gitorious.org/misc-gdb-stuff/misc-gdb-stuff/trees/master/misc_gdb/lockstep